# Bash: Continuously check processes running or not with some parameters

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to create script that will check continuously process status running or not. If process will not run, script should catch it and restart it in a seconds. How can I run continuously this script on the system and how should I change the script via ---> Important points: it should take as parameters these: 1-seconds to wait between attempts to restart service, 2- number of attempts and 3- generate logs of events. Nginx is a example for the process. It can be replaceable.

```
#!/bin/bash 
SERVICE="nginx" 
if pgrep -x "$SERVICE" >/dev/null 
then 
    echo "$SERVICE is running" 
else 
    echo "$SERVICE stopped" 
    # start nginx if stopped 
    echo "$SERVICE starting" 
    systemctl start $SERVICE
fi
```

Comment: Why not use systemd?

Comment: @wowbagger I already use systemctl in the script. What do you mean? I just want to create bash script. Maybe I will integrate to cron for running continuously on OS. But parameters I need some advice.

Comment: @Dylan_ I guess wowbagger meant you can config the Nginx systemd service to make it auto-restart once it's stopped unexpectedly or crashed. You don't need to write your own script for that.

Comment: @Kent Nginx is a example service. It should be replaceable. I need to do it with bash script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

service="nginx"
seconds=2
retries=3

until (( retries-- == 0 ))
do
    property=$(systemctl show --property MainPID "$service")

    if [[ $property == MainPID=0 ]]
    then
        echo "$service stopped"
        echo "$service starting"
        systemctl start "$service" >& /dev/null
    else
        echo "$service is running"
        exit
    fi

    sleep "$seconds"
done

echo "$service is broken"
```

Comment: @Dylan_ I Updated the code for using `systemctl show --property MainPID` instead of `systemctl status` because it's faster and seems more reliable. With it you can also check the _statuses_ of several services with one `systemctl` call only, for example: `props=( $(systemctl show --property MainPID service1 service2 etc...) )`